# Repeating a set of processes on a list in Python (intermediate learner)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python, and have just written a script to automate extraction of data from a website and taking a screenshot from it.

I need to repeat the same process for a series of items, which I think makes sense to store in a list or tuple. The process needs to be repeated for items in the list in that order.

At the moment, I've copied the code for the first item, and pasted it below with the only amendment being the second item. I'm pretty sure I can do this in a simpler way and I think functions might be the way to go about this. I need some help on how to go about this.

The structure looks like this now:

```
Step 1 performed on item A
Step 2 performed on item A
Step 3 performed on item A
Step 1 performed on item B
Step 2 performed on item B
Step 3 performed on item B
```

Should I be doing this?

```
list = [A, B]

def function Step 1
def function Step 2
def function Step 3
```

Questions:

1. How can I state that I would like the Steps to be done to A first,
   and then repeated on B in that order?
2. I might have a C, D, E in future. How can I end the process? Would
   it be by using break?
3. Would it be better to have Steps 1-3 all combined in one defined
   function instead, since they all have to be done to each item?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You ask the right questions, but they also tell me you're very much a beginning programmer. Since your question really comes down to "how do I program in Python?" (without being facetious), perhaps the best place to start would be some tutorials or courses? See what you can learn about loops, functions, and basic data structures and perhaps come back when you have more specific issues. Don't take it the wrong way - you're clearly looking to learn, but questions this broad and basic are perhaps not best answered on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks but I did state that I'm a beginner at the start of the post. I've taken several beginner online courses, which is how I've managed to write my basic script to address a real problem (and I'm very happy about that). But these courses only ever give beginner definitions of what each element is, without venturing into something "real" or putting them all together like what I'm trying to do. And working with other programmers or being mentored by them seems the next stage. If you have good "I'm past definitions" courses I'd appreciate recommendations.

Comment: Use joblib package. It simply run a command with list of paramets in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `while` loop and `for` loop:

```
while True:
    for item in listname:  # Item shall be A, B, C
     Commands Here         # Apply rules of functions here
```